# Issue with enabling gps programmatically

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-gps

I have written a code to check if gps is enabled or not and if not enabled, user gets a prompt asking to enable gps. On click of "OK", gps enables automatically. Following is the code I have written to check GPS connection.

```
private void locationPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 22);
            } else {
               gpssettings(this);
            }
        } else {
            gpssettings(this);
        }
    }

private void gpssettings(Context applicationContext) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task =
                LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    fireauth();
                } catch (ApiException exception) {
                    switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                            // user a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                        SplashScreen.this,
                                        99);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                                // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 99:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case RESULT_OK:
                        fireauth();
                        break;
                    case RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Requires gps connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 22){
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                gpssettings(this);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location permissions required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

But from last 10 days, it is behaving odd. Even if user click "OK", im getting result_cancelled in activityResult. Please check the code and tell if anything wrong or its some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this for enable GPS location on forcefully

Gradle:

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    Activity activity;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity = this;

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            locationChecker(mGoogleApiClient);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public void locationChecker(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(activity, 1000);

                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No use, still the same.

Comment: Please use this
final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
       // Disable
    } else { 
  // Enable
 }

Comment: where should i add these lines?

Comment: Any screen of your app where you want to check GPS on or off.